# Why <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}"> doesn't work?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-style, targettype

I have a `CheckBox`, `RadioButton` and `TextBox`, and want to control their enablement using binding:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}"> <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsNotScanning}"/> </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}"> <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsNotScanning}"/> </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"> <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsNotScanning}"/> </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

That's great, but why the following doesn't work?

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsNotScanning}"/>
    </Style>    
</Grid.Resources>
```

After all, they all inherit `Control`, right?